Calculate $ \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i} \right] $ when $X_i$'s are independent (but not identical) exponential random variable
I want to calculate $$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i} \right] $$ when $ X_i $'s are independent (but not identical) exponential distribution.
I found solution when $N=2$ in this post: Expected value of $X/(X+Y)$.
I also know that if $X_i$'s are i.i.d. exponential distribution, $ \frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i} $ follows beta-distribution.
But I want a general case solution.
How can I solve this problem? Does this variable follow well-known distribution?
Thank you.

Some thoughts.
Using the identity
$$\frac{1}{u} = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-s u}\, \mathrm{d} s,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i} \right]
 &= \mathbb{E} \left[\int_0^\infty X_1\mathrm{e}^{- s(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i)}\,\mathrm{d} s \right] \\
 &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}\left[X_1\mathrm{e}^{- s(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i)}\right]\,\mathrm{d} s \\
 &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}\left[X_1\mathrm{e}^{-sX_1}\right]
 \prod_{i=2}^N\mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-s X_i}\right]\,\mathrm{d} s\\
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda_1}{(s + \lambda_1)^2}
 \prod_{i=2}^N \frac{\lambda_i}{s + \lambda_i}\,\mathrm{d} s.
\end{align*}
Ex. 1: Expected value of $X/(X+Y)$,
$N = 2, \lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 2, 
\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} \right]
= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\frac{2}{s + 2}\,\mathrm{d} s = 2 - 2\ln 2$.
Ex. 2: $\lambda_i = \lambda, \forall i$
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i} \right] = \frac{1}{N}.$$

Thank you for your answer!

@JaehyunKim You are welcome.

Here is a more analytical approach.
We want to find $E(Z)$ where
$$Z=X_1/\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=X_1/ \left(X_1+\sum_{i=2}^n X_i\right)=X_1/(X_1+Y)$$
where the $X_i$ random variables are independent exponential distributions all with different parameters:
$$X_i \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda_i)$$
and $Y$ has a hypoexponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_2, \ldots,\lambda_n$.
The pdf of $Y$ is
$$\left(\prod_{i=2}^n \lambda_i\right) \sum_{i=2}^n \left(e^{-y \lambda_i} /\prod_{\substack{j=2 \\j\neq i}}^n {(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)}\right)$$
The mean of $Z$ can be found with the following:
$$\mu=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{x_1}{x_1+y} e^{-x_1 \lambda_1} \lambda_1 \left(\prod_{i=2}^n \lambda_i\right) \sum_{i=2}^n \left(e^{-y \lambda_i}/ \prod_{\substack{j=2 \\j\neq i}}^n {(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)}\right) dy dx_1$$
$$=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)  \sum_{i=2}^n
\frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{j=2 \\j\neq i}}^n {(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{x_1}{x_1+y} e^{-x_1 \lambda_1-y \lambda_i} dy \  dx_1$$
$$= \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)  \sum_{i=2}^n
\frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{j=2 \\j\neq i}}^n {(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)}} \frac{\lambda_i-\lambda_1 (1+\log(\lambda_i/\lambda_1))}{\lambda_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_i)^2}$$

Oh I got it. I will search more about hypoexponential distribution. Thank you.

And what I showed is definitely dependent on all of the $\lambda$ values not having any common values.

When some of the $\lambda$ values are equal, you should be able to take the limit of $\mu$ as say $\lambda_2 \rightarrow \lambda_1$ and as many times as needed.  (I offer no proof of this.)

Oh thank you, I missed that part. In my situation, some of lambda values can be same.

While it might not play well in this forum, using a Computer Algebra System - CAS - (Mathematica, Maple, etc.) can make this much easier to implement (and life is too short to spend too much time with algebra if you're going to need multiple combinations of $\lambda$ values).

@Villa  Thanks for catching that.  I left off the / in that line.  It is now fixed.

@Villa I rejected your correctly done edit but I think that just putting in the missing / is simpler.  But I could be wrong about that.

One possibility that is at least suggestive is to generate the means for various values of $n$ and then look for a unifying pattern.
Using Mathematica (but I'm sure Maple and MATLAB can do this in a similar manner) one can produce a table of means for various values of $n$:
Format[\[Lambda][i_]] := Subscript[\[Lambda], i]
Format[x[i_]] := Subscript[x, i]
m = Table[{n, Mean[TransformedDistribution[x[1]/Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}],
  Table[x[i] \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda][i]], {i, 1, n}]]]},                          
    {n, 2, 4}];
TableForm[m]


One can see that the denominator has the form
$$\left(\prod _{i=2}^n (\lambda (1)-\lambda (i))\right) \prod _{i=1}^{n-1} \prod _{j=i+1}^n (\lambda (i)-\lambda (j))$$
The next step would be to determine the form of the numerator for a general value of $n$.

Then how to determine numerator term?

These links might help:  https://scholarworks.utrgv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1111&context=mss_fac and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution.

And, yes, my "answer" is just an approach to "get" a result rather than a mathematical proof of the result.  That's what I was attempting to say in the first sentence of my answer.  Do you just need the result?  Or is a proof essential?

Oh thank you for your answer! I need a proof but for verification it is enough to get just the result.
